# Add array in exiting array in php

Tags: php, arrays, save, addition, recode

I have a json. First i have to decode then add loop on a specific key of json.

```
public function saveRecode() {
    $json ='{"productID":"1","productPrice":"5585.00","productDetails":{"productImage":"https:\/\/development.modeconfigurator.com\/eCommerce\/backdrop.jpg","TABLE TOP":"COPPER DISTRESSED","TABLE FRAME":"RAL 5024 PASTEL BLUE"},"_":"1583172411557"}';

    $jsonDecode = json_decode($json, true);
    foreach ($jsonDecode["productDetails"] as $key => $value) {
        $options = [
            '0' => [
                'sort_order' => '1',
                'title' => $key,
                'price_type' => 'fixed',
                'price' => '',
                'type' => 'drop_down',
                'is_require' => '0',
                'values' => [
                    '0' =>[
                        'title' => $value,
                        'price' => '',
                        'price_type' => 'fixed',
                        'sku' => '',
                        'sort_order' => '0',
                        'is_delete' => '0',
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ];
    }
    foreach ($options as $arrayOption) {
        $this->_logger->debug("enter in opt ");
        $this->_logger->info(print_r($arrayOption,true));
        $option = $this->_options
            ->setProductId($_product->getId())
            ->setStoreId($_product->getStoreId())
            ->addData($arrayOption);
        $option->save();
        $_product->addOption($option);
    }
}
```

In database only last recode save. But i want to save all parameters please take a loop.

[image]

Comment: ok, but only one recode save in database

Comment: You're overwriting `$options` each time through the loop, not appending to it.

Comment: then how appending please?

Comment: You can append new items to your array by using `$options[] = $item` or by using `array_push($options, $item)`. See here: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're replacing `$options` each time through the loop, not adding a new element to it. It should be:

```
$options = [];
foreach ($jsonDecode["productDetails"] as $key => $value) {
    $options[] = [
        'sort_order' => '1',
        'title' => $key,
        'price_type' => 'fixed',
        'price' => '',
        'type' => 'drop_down',
        'is_require' => '0',
        'values' => [
            '0' =>[
                'title' => $value,
                'price' => '',
                'price_type' => 'fixed',
                'sku' => '',
                'sort_order' => '0',
                'is_delete' => '0',
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: i have implement your solution, now at the time only 1 key ("productImage") save with all three values. loop in screenshot  https://ibb.co/Y0LdWGq

Comment: You're only looping over `$jsonDecode['productDetails']`, why do you expect anything else to be saved?

Comment: each key with value mean three recode should save. look in screenshot i need exactly this   https://ibb.co/Qf6C0JW

Comment: Where do you set `$_product`?

Comment: I don't know how your `addData()` and `addOption()` methods work, so I can't be sure that you've constructed the `$options` element correctly. But I can't see why my code is making them all part of the same option.

Comment: yes you are right $option element correctly i have check log.
it make problem when i am saving these option in database.thanks for answer me.

i have not power to give you +1 :(  accept answer